# generate random graph with named vertices

Tags: c++, boost, named, boost-graph, vertices

I'm new to boost and i am trying to build up a distributed random graph generated by the erdos algorithm. All goes well since i specialize the internal_vertex_name template to work with named vertices as suggested in [the doc](http://osl.iu.edu/research/pbgl/documentation/distributed_adjacency_list.html#named-vertices).

You can find the [code here](http://codepad.org/8y0huftW).

I get a lot of compilation errors like:

```
boost/graph/distributed/shuffled_distribution.hpp:62:56: error: ‘const struct boost::graph::distributed::hashed_distribution<std::basic_string<char> >’ has no member named ‘block_size’

error: ‘const struct boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::distributedS<boost::graph::distributed::mpi_process_group, boost::vecS>, boost::directedS, TNode, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, int>
>::base_distribution_type’ has no member named ‘local

boost/graph/distributed/adjlist/initialize.hpp:29:5: error: invalid conversion from ‘long unsigned int’ to ‘const char*’
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: I made a few formatting edits for you. You can find hints (and a link to more complete docs) in the sidebar of the editing page.

Comment: And BTW--it is generally not appropriate to [re-post questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257933/bgl-generate-random-graph-with-named-vertices). Edit them instead. Note that tagging is important in bringing your questions to the attentions of users who can answer them. You left off the very popular [c++] tag, and that probably didn't help.

Comment: sorry for the duplicated post i got an error the first time and i pressed the submit button without check if it was already posted or not. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: @user: Ah, this may be a bug, but it happens so rarely that no time has been invested in it. You should be able to delete the other one, a long as it has no answers.